# is it possible to implement a css template like this one into my jsp's?

Tags: css, jsp

I have a site I made using jsp's and I need to stylize it. Can I somehow implement a css template like this one in my jsp's? [css template](http://www.freecsstemplates.org/preview/orangeflower/)

If so, how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  It is definitely possible.  [Here is a tutorial on JSP templates](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/javaserverpages/jsp_templates/).  It teaches you about the include directive, which allows you to include static content such as HTML files like:

```
<%@include file='header.html'%>
```

or the template taglib that allows you to include templates with

```
<%@ taglib uri='/WEB-INF/tlds/template.tld' prefix='template' %>

<html><head><title><template:get name='title'/></title></head>
<body background='graphics/background.jpg'>

<table>
   <tr valign='top'><td><template:get name='sidebar'/></td>
      <td><table>
            <tr><td><template:get name='header'/></td></tr>
            <tr><td><template:get name='content'/></td></tr>
            <tr><td><template:get name='footer'/></td></tr>
         </table>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
</body></html>
```

From a template or from a raw JSP file you can absolutely reference CSS.  It's fairly simple.  You reference the CSS in your HTML tags in the JSP the same way you would regularly:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="common.css" type="text/css">
```

For more information see [W3](http://www.w3.org/TR/html40/present/styles.html#h-14.2).

Comment: Your eHow (ugh) link is instructions on how to take a static CSS file and import its contents into `<style></style>` tags within the page. It completely defeats the point of having a separate CSS file, and will cause the browser to be unable to cache the CSS.

Comment: Thanks a ton guys!!! I'll work it out and let you know how it goes. I can't wait until I get to the point where I am the one helping on here..